Fibonacci doubling using two squarings?
If $F(n)$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number, then given $F(n)$ and $F(n-1)$, the classic "fast doubling" way of obtaining $F(2n)$ and $F(2n+1)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
F(2n) &= F(n) \left(2F(n+1) - F(n)\right)\\
F(2n+1) &= F(n+1)^2 + F(n)^2
\end{align}
$$
When implementing this for arbitrary precision integers, this requires two squarings and one multiplication of large integers. It can also be done in two multiplications. However, when implementing multiplication using the fast Fourier transform, it turns out that squaring is cheaper than multiplying unrelated numbers (two FFT applications instead of three). And indeed GMP uses the following formulas:
$$
\begin{align}
F(2n) &= F(2n+1) - F(2n-1)\\
F(2n-1) &= F(n)^2 + F(n-1)^2\\
F(2n+1) &= 4F(n)^2 - F(n-1)^2 + 2*(-1)^n
\end{align}
$$
This uses only two squarings of arbitrary precision integers. The first two formulas are easy enough to prove. The third one I've not been able to prove.
Where does this third equation, $F(2n+1) = 4F(n)^2 - F(n-1)^2 + 2*(-1)^n$, come from?

Have you tried using Binet's formula to verify it?

We can just mess around starting with $F_{2n+1}^2 = F_{n+1}^2 + F_n^2$ and see what we get. We want to get rid of $F_{n+1}$, so substituting $F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$ gives
$$\begin{align*} F_{2n+1}^2 &= (F_n + F_{n-1})^2 + F_n^2 \\
 &= 2F_n^2 + 2F_n F_{n-1} + F_{n-1}^2. \end{align*}$$
We want to get a $4 F_n^2$ term and a subtraction, so that suggests substituting $F_{n-1} = F_n - F_{n-2}$ into the middle term to get
$$\begin{align*} F_{2n+1}^2 &= 2F_n^2 + 2 F_n (F_n - F_{n-2}) + F_{n-1}^2 \\
 &= 4F_n^2 - 2F_n F_{n-2} + F_{n-1}^2. \end{align*}$$
Equating this with the desired identity, this means the desired identity is equivalent to
$$- 2 F_n F_{n-2} + F_{n-1}^2 = - F_{n-1}^2 + 2 (-1)^n$$
or, simplifying a bit,
$$F_{n-1}^2 - F_n F_{n-2} = (-1)^n.$$
This is apparently called Cassini's identity. It has a nice interpretation in terms of the Fibonacci matrix $F = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. This matrix has the wonderful property that its powers generate the Fibonacci numbers:
$$F^n = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}.$$
This can be used to explain where the doubling formulas come from; they are equivalent to the single identity $F^{2n} = F^n F^n$. It also produces a conceptual proof of Binet's formula using the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix, which is described with some very nice animations here. (Binet's formula can be used to "cheese" proofs of some Fibonacci identities, including the desired identity, but I'd rather not do that if possible.)
We get Cassini's identity from here by taking determinants: since $\det F = -1$ we get
$$\boxed{ F_{n+1} F_{n-1} - F_n^2 = (-1)^n }$$
which is equivalent to what we wanted. You can also give a more hands-on proof where you define $d_n = F_{n+1} F_{n-1} - F_n^2$ and apply the Fibonacci recurrence a few times to show that $d_n = - d_{n-1}$ but I think the matrix argument makes it clearer what's going on and why something like this should be true at all.

Thanks! I hadn't thought of making $F_n$ appear from $F_{n-1}$ by using $F_{n-1} = F_n - F_{n-2}$. The matrix exponentiation (or indeed working over $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle x^2 - x - 1 \rangle$ and taking $x^n$) indeed gives the usual fast doubling formulas, this particular form is just better suited for very large integer calculations :)
